# Use awk to find all Ports for each IP that have https open

Tags: awk, nmap

I'd like to print all ips (IP space Port) which have open https ports given a gnmap file.

An example output for a line that has only https running on port 443:

```
123.123.123.123 443
```

A more elaborate example input and desired output (not all test-cases in there):

```
Host: 123.123.123.123 ()  Ports: 80/open/tcp//http?///, 443/open/tcp//https?///, 8083/closed/tcp//us-srv///, 65001/closed/tcp/////        Ignored State: filtered (65531) Seq Index: 262  IP ID Seq: Randomized
Host: 123.123.123.124 ()  Ports: 80/open/tcp//http?///, 443/open/tcp//https?///, 10443/open/tcp//https///, 65001/closed/tcp/////        Ignored State: filtered (65531) Seq Index: 262  IP ID Seq: Randomized
Host: 123.123.123.125 ()  Ports: 80/open/tcp//http?///, 443/open/tcp//https?///, 8083/closed/tcp//us-srv///, 8445/open/tcp//https///, 65001/closed/tcp/////        Ignored State: filtered (65531) Seq Index: 262  IP ID Seq: Randomized
Host: 123.123.123.126 ()  Ports: 1337/open/tcp//https?///, 8083/closed/tcp//us-srv///, 65001/closed/tcp/////        Ignored State: filtered (65531) Seq Index: 262  IP ID Seq: Randomized
```

The output for this file should be:

```
123.123.123.123 443
123.123.123.124 443
123.123.123.124 10443
123.123.123.125 443
123.123.123.125 8445
123.123.123.126 1337
```

What would be the awk solution for this?

Comment: By "it needs to have two open ports where the second is the https port" do you mean that if ports 80, 123, and 443 were open, you do not want to see that line, because the third port, not the second port, is 443?

Comment: No the solution I've tried needs that to work, but I'd rather have it find out all https ports and print "ip port".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got the “more or less open ports below 443” case correctly, this should be a generic solution handling it correctly:

```
awk '/\/https\// {for(i=5;i<=NF;i++)if($i~"/open/.+/https/"){sub("/.*","",$i); print $2" "$i}}' nmap-synscan.gnmap
```

Comment: if "there are more or less open ports below 443", your solution will failed.

Comment: Yes. I intended to ask clarification for that case. No idea how the input and output would look in that case.

Comment: The question was poorly formulated, it's re-formulated. My bad

Comment: If by “only https” you mean strictly just “https”, excluding “https?”, then this edit does it. However in this case none of them is “running on port 443” in your example.

Comment: The answer has been accepted, but I don't see the rules to find `open` ports. So the command should be updated to (if part): `if($i~"/https/"&&$i~"/open/")`

Comment: @BMW, you are right. Edited. (Actually, if would not be accepted, I would delete my answer. The input and output samples in the question are still unrelated, so I am still not sure whether my answer is correct.)

Comment: @user857990 please update expected output in your question

Answer (score 0):

`awk`'s `split` function can be used to extract fields from the gnmap output.

`split("443/open/tcp//https?///, a, "/"); print a[1]` gives you `443`.

Use this to print the ip and port for the lines that show at least one open https port:

```
awk '{ for (f=5; f <= NF; f++) {
         split($f,a,"/");
         if (a[2] != "open") continue;
         if (a[5] ~ /https.*/) {
           print $2, a[1];
         }
       }
      }' nmap-synscan.gnmap
```

Use this to print the ip and port for the lines that show an open https port and at least one open port below https:

```
awk '{ lowopen = 0;
       for (f=5; f <= NF; f++) {
         split($f,a,"/");
         if (a[2] != "open") continue;
         if (a[1] < 443) lowopen++;
         if (lowopen && a[5] ~ /https.*/) {
           print $2, a[1];
         }
       }
      }' nmap-synscan.gnmap
```

Edit: to answer your second question, use this to print the ip and port for lines where exactly the second open port is https:

```
awk '{ split($6,a,"/");
       if (a[5] ~ /https.*/) {
         print $2, a[1];
       }
      }' nmap-synscan.gnmap
```

Answer (score 0):

This is better suited to parsing by regular expressions than by fields. Why not use Perl?

```
$ perl -lne '/Host:\s*([\d\.]+)/; $h=$1; 
            print "$h $_" for (/(\d+)\/open[^\s]+https/g);
           ' file 
123.123.123.123 443
123.123.123.123 10443
123.123.123.123 443
123.123.123.123 8443
123.123.123.123 443
123.123.123.123 443
```

The first line just captures the host IP and saves it as `$h`. The second line, matches all numbers that are followed by `/open` then one or more non-whitespace characters and then `https`. That should match all open `https` ports. The `print` statement will print the host name (`$h`) and each of the matched ports (saved as the special variable `$_`).

Comment: Unnecessarily complicated

Comment: @MariusMatutiae revenge voting huh :) ? At least it returns what the OP asked for and is the shortest answer on the page so I don't see how it is complicated.

Comment: No, not revenge voting: the OP asks for an *awk* solution, yours falls clearly outside the OP

Comment: @MariusMatutiae fair enough. In general though, answers providing different approaches are encouraged here (not asking you ti change your vote, not really bothered, just so you know for other As).

Answer (score 0):

You can give `nmap(1)` a set of ports to check directly, i.e., in this case just add `-PS80,443`.